# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).lightGallery is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightgallery

when I try to click the link it shows this in browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).lightGallery is not a    function(anonymous function) @ index.html:250dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

and this is the code I used:

```
    $('#gallery').on('click', function() {
    $(this).lightGallery({
        dynamic: true,
        dynamicEl: [{
            "src": 'assets/images/gallery/1.jpg',
            'thumb': 'assets/images/gallery/thumbs/1.jpg',
            'subHtml': '<h4>Fading Light</h4><p>Classic view from Rigwood Jetty on Coniston Water an old archive shot similar to an old post but a little later on.</p>'
        }, {
            'src': 'assets/images/gallery/2.jpg',
            'thumb': 'assets/images/gallery/thumbs/2.jpg',
            'subHtml': "<h4>Bowness Bay</h4><p>A beautiful Sunrise this morning taken En-route to Keswick not one as planned but I'm extremely happy I was passing the right place at the right time....</p>"
        }, {
            'src': 'assets/images/gallery/3.jpg',
            'thumb': 'assets/images/gallery/thumbs/3.jpg',
            'subHtml': "<h4>Coniston Calmness</h4><p>Beautiful morning</p>"
        }]
    })
});
```

bear in mind I am using the Dynamic Mode in lightGallery.

1. I already included the lightGallery library before and the jQuery library before it.
2. I have tried to substitute the $ with jQuery.
3. I also tried the "semicolon solution" but with no luck.

this is the whole libraries i included:

```
    <script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/tether/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/smooth-scroll/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/viewportChecker/jquery.viewportchecker.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/cookies-alert-plugin/cookies-alert-core.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/cookies-alert-plugin/cookies-alert-script.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/dropdown/js/script.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/touchSwipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/jarallax/jarallax.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap-carousel-swipe/bootstrap-carousel-swipe.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/jquery-mb-ytplayer/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/theme/js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/mobirise-slider-video/script.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/formoid/formoid.min.js"></script>
  <!-- lightgallery -->
  <script src="assets/theme/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/theme/js/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/theme/js/lg-fullscreen.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/theme/js/lg-share.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/theme/js/lg-zoom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/theme/js/lg-autoplay.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please provide the html, especially any scripts you have included in the head

Comment: Is there any other error on console?

Comment: no other errors on console!!

Comment: is the script on this path `assets/theme/js/lightgallery.min.js`? Can you access that path on browser?

Comment: yes the browser can access it lady @ClaudioRedi please help!!

Comment: Which script file is the code you provide contained in? This file will need to be called after the lightgallery script files.

Comment: @AdamP. I included the code directly inside the html file inside the script tag and directly after I included the lightgallery library!!

Comment: I have update the code but it is still the same:
https://jsfiddle.net/hamzaabdullahmoh/c4quqf0v/#&togetherjs=qz2kFk037N

Comment: thanks for all of you!! ClaudioRedi, depperm AdamP and to the jsfiddle unknown soldier #Carious Cat

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wooooooooooo Haaaaaa I finally solved it, and the problem was maybe with local version I have!!
When I switched to the cdnjs version it worked PERFECT!!!
a huge THANKS for all of you!!
all I did is replace the local ones with the cdn links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.3.2/css/lightgallery.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.3.2/js/lightgallery.js"></script>
```

Comment: for some reason even in 2018 the local ones do not work and cdn versions do

Comment: This can not be the solution, I use this local and then what?

Comment: See my answer maybe it helps someone.

Comment: Just copying this lightgallery.js and putting it in my own fixed the issue. It has 500 lines of code less but hasn't found any reduced functionality yet.

Answer (score 4):

in the head

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js/master/dist/css/lightgallery.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

your html.

```
<div id="lightgallery">
  <a href="img/img1.jpg">
      <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="img/img2.jpg">
      <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

in the body. at the end after jquery

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js/master/dist/js/lightgallery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-pager.js/master/dist/lg-pager.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-autoplay.js/master/dist/lg-autoplay.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-fullscreen.js/master/dist/lg-fullscreen.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-zoom.js/master/dist/lg-zoom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-hash.js/master/dist/lg-hash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-share.js/master/dist/lg-share.js"></script>
<script>
   lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!  #Ozal_Zarbaliyev

Answer (score 2):

I make sure, this plugin was the last script in been called.
I also wrapped the code inside the ready function.

In addition, I show how to use a variant to select elements from the DOM. I'm using jQuery and running all from my local server. The sources of lightgallery are from 2018, downloaded from the repository, manually.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.post img').wrap(function(){
          return "<div class='gallery' data-src='" + $( this ).attr("src") + "'></div>";
        });

        lightGallery(document.querySelector('.post'), {selector: ".gallery"});
      });
    </script>
```